# How to use pure C files in an objective-c project?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Simple question:

I have created a bunch of C helper routines and am trying to include them in a project. I had assumed something like the following would be ok.

MyFuncs.h

```
typedef struct
{
    float n;
} MyStruct;

float Operation(MyStruct ms);
```

MyFuncs.m

```
#import "MyFuncs.h"

float Operation(MyStruct ms)
{
    return ms.n * ms.n;
}
```

However, I'm getting a linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" and "Operation(MyStruct) referenced from x"

Is there some other way that header/implemenation C files need to be set-up to work?

Note: This is for an iOS project using Xcode 4.5.

Comment: SOrry, I should have said this is for an iOS project using the XCode 4.5 IDE

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your comment into the question -- you're free to edit your own questions if you realize you left something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no problem with using pure C.  Usually, the source files will be named `*.c` instead of `*.m`, but renaming `*.c` to `*.m` shouldn't cause errors.

However, there's a clue:

> `Operation(MyStruct)` referenced from `x`

If the linker knows the type of the function parameters, it's because you're calling the function from C++ code.  You will have to put `extern "C" { ... }` in the header as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct
{
    float n;
} MyStruct;

float Operation(MyStruct ms);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you don't have any C++ in your project (including Objective-C++ `*.mm` files), then this isn't your problem.

Comment: Make sure also to put `extern "C"` inside an `#ifdef __cplusplus`

Comment: @asveikau: Righto.  I've been doing it all automatically for so long it's easy to forget...

Comment: Great spot! Yes, i'm migrating a couple of C++ classes to C to simplify my project a little.

Answer (score 0):

If it's pure c then "MyFuncs.c" instead of "MyFuncs.m" will be better.

Answer (score -4):

Call the implementation file with extension .mm like MyFuncs.mm.

Comment: Objective-C++ (.mm) and C (.c) are very different languages.