# iOS: Accessing singleton method from C implementation

Tags: objective-c, c, singleton

I have an Objective-C singleton method the I need to access from C implementation. Any of you knows how can I do this?.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the C code in a .m file or a .c file?

Comment: @rmaddy is .c file. I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Can't be done from a .c file. C knows nothing about Objective-C syntax. C code in a .m file would work but then it's really Objective-C code.

Comment: @rmaddy can I create a .h file with a macro to execute the objective-c code?

Comment: Possibly but only if the .h file is included into a .m file, not a .c file.

Comment: @rmaddy can you post an example ?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489504/